# How to display the nearby locations without using google places api?

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps

Hi I am developing an android app where I want to display the nearby locations to the user using GPS.

I found many tutorials which recommended the use of google places api but my problem is that I don't want to use google places api but I need to input the names of the stores in a MySQL database and then use this database to display the stores in the google maps and as a list using this.

Can you post some tutorials where I can learn to do this as I am really new to android.

Comment: hi can you say where you want to display current location

Comment: in google maps I want to put a marker to display my location and also the nearby locations with separate markers for both.

Comment: go throght this hope help u lot kindohm.com/blog/2010/10/06/androidgpsgeocoding/

Comment: Thank you if you have any more tutorials please let me know and post it as an answer so that I can accept...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) for Android. Here you can draw markers on the  map by specifying the co-ordinates of a location. You can also attach labels, touch-responsive dialogs etc. to the overlays.

Store your location data in your database including it's name and lat,long co-ordinates. Then you can retrieve and pass this data to the api and draw overlays and markers to represent the places as you like.

The given link has many samples and tutorials as well.

Comment: I want to get the values using gps so that it is upto date rather than givig it hardcoded can this be done?

Comment: you can either give the co-ordinates and draw markers using the google maps api or you can give the names of places and get their co-ordinates using the google places api.

Comment: I already have a google map api which I am using to display the maps

Comment: hmmmm oh ill try getting the location and mark the places on the map.

Comment: if you want the co-ordinates from names then you need to use google places api or some other third party service such as foursquare

Comment: I am using google places api also but the problem is that in my app I have 3 buttons and in the 1st button I need to display the nearby locations in the google map and in the 2nd button I need to display the nearby locations in the form of a list these 2 I am doing perfectly but in the 3rd button I need to display all the locations of a particular type present in a particular city where I am facing the problem so I was thinking of hardcoding the values in a db and getting the location using GPS to display the values. Can you tell me if this can be done?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what your requirements are but I guess it can be done. Try it out. If it doesn't work, post it as another question with a detailed explanation and all your code.

Comment: I am trying for the past 2 weeks and the best answer I got is that google places api limits the number of places that can be shown to 60 and with a range of 50km. As I am new to android I want some help I dunno how to do the 3rd part of my requirement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24011/discussion-between-anup-cowkur-and-user1929242)